# why IIS or Apache do not use all CPU capacity under full load?

Tags: multithreading, performance, apache, iis, cpu

I have written two simple services returning a constant value. After running 100'000 concurrent client threads to consum them on the same machine in separated experiments, I found out none of CPU cores are utilized over 10 percent. Even after changing the client code to generate client threads in an infinitive loop, server core utilization doesn't changed.
Is this behavior because of some none CPU instructions which are executed via each request?
If yes what kind of structure are them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tasks are I/O bound, rather than being CPU bound.

Meaning whatever load you create, the RAM and Disk and Network activity will max out long before the CPU will.

And in some cases, after reaching a certain percentage of CPU load, it just will not increase any more because the nature of the load is utilizing only a sub-set of functions that are finite in nature.

In my experience, if Apache is using 100% of the CPU, you have a bad PHP script or a faulty PHP process.